# Kubernetes on GCE / Prevent pods undergoing an eviction with "The node was low on compute resources."

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes

Painful investigation on aspects that so far are not that highlighted by documentation (at least from what I've googled)

My cluster's kube-proxy became evicted (+-experienced users might be able to consider the faced issues). Searched  a lot, but no clues about how to have them up again.

Until describing the concerned pod gave a clear reason : "The node was low on compute resources."

Still not that experienced with resources balance between pods/deployments and "physical" compute, how would one 'prioritizes' (or similar approach) to make sure specific pods will never end up in such a state ?

The cluster has been created with fairly low resources in order to get our hands on while keeping low costs and eventually witnessing such problems (`gcloud container clusters create deemx --machine-type g1-small --enable-autoscaling --min-nodes=1 --max-nodes=5 --disk-size=30`), is using g1-small is to prohibit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using iptables-based kube-proxy (the current best practice), then kube-proxy being killed should not immediately cause your network connectivity to fail, but new services and updates to endpoints will stop working.  Still, your apps should continue to work, but degrade slowly.
If you are using userspace kube-proxy, you might want to upgrade.

The error message sounds like it was due to memory pressure on the machine.

When there is memory pressure, Kubelet tries to terminate things in order of lowest to highest [QoS level](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/design/resource-qos.md).

If your kube-proxy pod is not using Guaranteed resources, then you might want to change that.

Other things to look at:

- if kube-proxy suddenly used a lot more memory, it could be terminated.  If you made a huge number of pods or services or endpoints, this could cause it to use more memory.
- if you started processes on the machine that are not under kubernetes control, that could cause kubelet to make an incorrect decision about what to terminate.  Avoid this.
- It is possible that on such a small machine as a g1-small, the amount of node resources held back is insufficient, such that too much guaranteed work got put on the machine -- see [allocatable vs capacity](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/proposals/node-allocatable.md).  This might need tweaking.
- [Node oom documentation](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/out-of-resource/#node-oom-behavior)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this pointers, it was quite painful but we're now better off having experienced those issues  now. I have to say we're still getting started into it all; simply speaking would you recommend strictly tuning the resources allocated to each deployments (sorry for the example, I'm talking about it https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/guestbook/redis-slave-deployment.yaml#L34 and the following line ), or should we get a larger picture about it ?

Comment: Recommend you set memory request much more than you think you need and limit to 2x that.  Then apply some load to the service.  Run [kubectl top](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_top_pod/) while applying load.  Watch the usage grow as load is applied.   Soak to check for leaks.  Based on that data, update memory request to 20% above max usage observed, and limit to 50% above.

Comment: You'll tell me that it is not related but so far I find it contradictory; we've enabled autoscaling, how this does not relate ? At first and without extended knowledge, one could simply expect the number of instances to grow